# datatables + lengthMenu + All + serverside processing + not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/5gpLcfkr/) is a basic datatables fiddle. 
This is the [default](https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthMenu) and the dropdowns will show the follwoing `Show options 10, 25, 50, 75 and 100 records:`

Now what I would like to get working is the `"lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ]` which I can in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5gpLcfkr/1/). But what if I use server side processing, this is where the `All` option does not work for me. The others do. When I select `All` it  dispalys the data that it was showing and the at the bottom says `No data found in the server`

As far as i Know the only difference is the data comes from the server. Can anyone advise how i can trouble shoot this? As far as I can tell when I select `All` I am sending `length:-1` and for `10` it is `length:10` so not sure why `All` is not working

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
                "lengthMenu" : [[ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],[ '10', '25', '50', 'All' ]],
                //"pageLength": 25,
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax":{
                    url :"employee-grid-data.php", // json datasource
                    type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                    error: function(){  // error handling
                        $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                        $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
                        $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");

                    }
                }                   
            } );
        } );
```

Comment: show the `html` code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using server-side processing, you should ignore the `start` and `length` request parameters **ONLY IF** the `length` parameters is `-1` in your PHP script in order to return all records.

Comment: fuuny how the(my) brain works, that thought came to me randomly some hours later whilst doig something else completely.

Answer (score 1):

"lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ]

1)Means that "ALL" is assigned the value of -1.

2)that's the reason why when u  select All your  are sending length:-1 and for 10 it is length:10

3)that's the reason why you also get **No data found in the server** - error

4)to proper this give this in your Controller

var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault() == "-1" ? Convert.ToString(YOUR_LIST.Count()) : Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();

5)this will tell if length == -1 then take your list total count so that it displays all  rows .

Comment: This solved my problem. I am using ASP NET Core

Answer (score -1):

For me, changing the 1st 3 of these parameters worked :

```
dom: 'ZBlrtip',
lengthMenu: [[100, 200, -1], [100, 200, "All"]],
bLengthChange: true,
order: [8, "desc"],
paging: true,
pageLength: 100,
serverSide: true
```